# Weblogic Admin Server Start issue - DataSource passwords got exparied

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

We are trying to use one of the existing weblogic 12c domain and It's DataSource passwords been expired. 
Since AdminServer is not responding correctly I tried to re-start AdminServer as well, Now I have changed the DB passwords and wanted to set the new passwords starting the AdminServer, but I cant start AdminServer it's failing complaining passwords are expired. (I could have get a way with this issue if i keep the admin server running and set the new passwords)

I can see DataSources are targeted to Admin Server and I thought if I untarget DS from AdminServer I could start AdminServer correctly. hence I removed the AdminServer as a target from config.xml and tried o start the Admin but it's still failing complaining passwords are expired. Is Config cached anywhere , looks like I am Admin is still using the old config file ? by the way I have tried removing the tmp folder as well.

Also, I tried encrypting the new password and placing on JDBC config files, Probably the way I encrypted was wrong. These are the steps I used to encrypt
1. Connect to WLST offline ( because Admin is not up)
2. Read domain
3. Call encrypt function for new password
4. Print the encrypt password

Anything wrong ? Appreciate any suggestion to resolve this issue.

Error is starting like this ,

```
Jun 22, 2015 4:38:04 PM oracle.security.jps.JpsStartup start
INFO: Jps initializing.
Jun 22, 2015 4:38:07 PM org.hibernate.validator.util.Version <clinit>
INFO: Hibernate Validator 12.1.3.0.0
Jun 22, 2015 4:38:07 PM  org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver detectJPA
INFO: Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.
[EL Severe]: ejb: 2015-06-22  16:38:11.173--ServerSession(143991231)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse  Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Error Code: 1017
Jun 22, 2015 4:38:11 PM oracle.security.jps.internal.common.config.AbstractSecurityStore getSecurityStoreVersion
WARNING: Unable to get the Version from Store returning the default oracle.security.jps.service.policystore.PolicyStoreException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
 Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Error Code: 1017
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.rdbms.JpsDBDataManager.processJPAException(JpsDBDataManager.java:2180)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.rdbms.JpsDBDataManager.init(JpsDBDataManager.java:1028)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.rdbms.JpsDBDataManager.jpsObjectBaseQuery(JpsDBDataManager.java:3089)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.policystore.rdbms.JpsDBDataManager.queryBaseObjects(JpsDBDataManager.java:5761)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.common.config.AbstractSecurityStore.getSecurityStoreVersion(AbstractSecurityStore.java:211)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.common.config.AbstractSecurityStore.getSecurityStoreVersion(AbstractSecurityStore.java:195)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.common.config.AbstractSecurityStore.<init>(AbstractSecurityStore.java:99)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.credstore.AbstractCredentialStore.<init>(AbstractCredentialStore.java:104)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.credstore.ldap.LdapCredentialStore.<init>(LdapCredentialStore.java:130)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.credstore.ldap.LdapCredentialStoreProvider.getInstance(LdapCredentialStoreProvider.java:235)
    at oracle.security.jps.internal.credstore.rdbms.DbmsCredentialStoreProvider.getInstance(DbmsCredentialStoreProvider.java:101)
    at oracle.security.opss.internal.runtime.ServiceContextManagerImpl.createContextInternal(ServiceContextManagerImpl.java:432)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First take backup of complete config folder inside domain.It looks like you are using rdbms policy store inside domain.So check for security-realm tag in config.xml there you will able to find encrypted password change the same using newly encrypted password and your admin server should start.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply, Yes your correct and I have followed http://cinqict.com/forums/topic/weblogic-12-1-3-opss-datasource-account-locked/ to fixed the issue.